# How can change my TabHost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost, 
e.g:

```
final TabHost tabs = getTabHost();
tabs.setup();
TabHost.TabSpec spec = null;
spec = tabs.newTabSpec("search");
spec.setContent(new Intent(this, Search.class));
spec.setIndicator("search");
tabs.addTab(spec);
```

in this tabhost is a Intent,and in the activity must change to other activity,
question is I hope the other actitivy at same tabhost switch? 
Can do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. Not clear what you mean with "...and in the activity must change to other activity, question is I hope the other actitivy at same tabhost switch?"

Comment: He wants to open a new activity, and he wants the new activity to open in the same place aka in the tab layout not in a new window.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem almost a 3 months ago. you can not replace the activity. Because activities are open in new screens. so you have to use the views and layout to achieve what you are want to do. use the setVisiblity and isShown methods you can hide and release yours view. Hope it make some sense on it.